# Is it worth it to shoot at the rocks in Beat Hazard?

Tags: beat-hazard

When asteroids begin to swarm on the screen in Beat Hazard, what I usually do is dodge them so I can rack up multiplier through Dare Devil. This allows me to score more points when ships come on screen.

However, by doing this, I miss out on the generous amount of points that can be scored by shooting the rocks down (I usually use superbombs for this purpose as it doesn't count as a shot for Dare Devil purposes). This changes in the last 15 seconds, where I instead decide to scrape the last points up by blowing up rocks.

Is my strategy suboptimal? Do I lose points if I blow rocks with a bomb instead of regular weaponry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From everything that I've read on the Beat Hazard forums, your general strategy is pretty spot on. Using the Dare Devil multiplier in the beginning of the song will generally net you more overall points than just shooting all the asteroids. Ships and bosses are worth more points than asteroids, so it's often recommended to hold off on shooting for as long as possible, potentially even until the first boss if you can. The multiplier score you rack up will end up optimizing your point acquisition much more. This effectiveness of this strategy can *sometimes* vary depending on the song you are playing, but overall it is sound.

Remember to be careful when using the Superbomb to clear the asteroids because it can end up splitting all the large ones at once, which will then send a ton of small ones flying around, which may end up killing you and your multiplier!

Comment: How do powerups fit into this, though?  Particularly at low levels, shooting the asteroids is the only obvious way to build up your weapons so that you can actually fight once aggressive enemies start coming onscreen...

Comment: @Margaret: Play, play and keep playing Beat Hazard. When you reach the Elite rank, something good will happen (I won't spoil it!), and you won't need to worry so much.

Comment: @DenilsonSá: Erm, what good thing happens?  I reached Elite Rank 2 now, and I still haven't noticed anything different...

Comment: For the classic Beat Hazard, IIRC, you would start with the volume and pow meters already filled, which means you are already powered-up from the beginning. I'm not sure about Beat Hazard Ultra.